# What real castle would be least expensive to visit from New Zealand?

Tags: budget, architecture

I'm going through the rules for board game called [Burg Appenzell](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/28089/burg-appenzell), and it says:

> The player who was the last to visit a real castle goes first.

None of us have been in a real castle, and I thought it would be good if I visit one. I live in New Zealand, what would be the least expensive castle (including the travel costs) for me to visit? It does not seem to be any castles where I live or in Australia, most of them seem to be in Europe with some in Americas, India and even Japan. What I'm really hoping asking this question, is for some real castle in Australia or closer that I was not able to find, but I don't think I'll be so lucky. Does not have to be a medieval castle, just a real castle.

Comment: This might not be the cheapest possible entry fee, but it's certainly the cheapest for you if you include travel costs: https://www.larnachcastle.co.nz/. The question is, what qualifies as a "real castle"? Do ruins count?

Comment: @mlc: Probably not. I doubt that it would qualify as a "real castle" under any but the loosest possible definition. It's basically a fancy house built in the late 19th century to look sort of like a traditional European castle.

Comment: @GregHewgill, I'm not that fussy, this does satisfy me, and more importantly, my wife, so if you would like write this as an answer I will be happy to accept.

Comment: Incidentally, Appenzell does not have a *Burg*, but at least a [*Schloss Appenzell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appenzell_Castle), which rather suggests a residential or palatial building than a fortified one. Great mountains near it, though.

Comment: The question should specify the rules for what counts as a "real castle" (minimum age, size, any particular features like battlements/moat/towers/dragon, degree of ruination, construction material, royal/noble residents, being called a castle by someone official/knowledgeable, history, etc). For instance, something 200 years old, made of stone, with battlements, towers, and a roof (preferably involved in a war).

Comment: I'd have to travel from Virginia to Columbus, OH, to the nearest "White Castle" ...

Comment: Is [ʻIolani Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBIolani_Palace) in Hawaii too new to be a castle? It certainly qualifies as a royal residence and is not too hard to get to from NZ.

Comment: @GregHewgill That looks like a castle and is literally called a castle so I think it should probably pass the test.

Comment: You should define "real castle" (I cannot access the site you link because of a firewall). As worded as it is now, saying that most real castles are in Europe sounds very condescending for non-Western cultures.

Comment: @Taladris huh??  Castles ("buildings with castellations") are a European thing and are, obviously, only in Europe.  Much as samurai are only in Japan, or a hundred other examples.

Comment: @Fattie: you are making a very specific definition. A more widely accepted definition of castle is a fortified structure built by a member of royalty or nobility. Focusing on castellation means focusing on the fortification part, but not all fortified places are castles. Many European castles have no castellations actually. There are many castles, with or without castellation, in Korea and Japan.

Comment: hi @Taladris ; we can only disagree.  FWIW consider my two comments under the answer with a picture of a shiro.

Comment: Does your definition of castle rules out Pillow Fort ,and Blanket Castle. It's unclear if real is means to rules out video games, and reproduction (lego). Or Kid Playground that features a tower and a house with a yellow crown on it. Note that the rules must be clear as Lordship is easy to buy, you may have to Duel my kids over the legitimacy of their well build castle, with proper chair tower, pillow castelation, card board pont levis

Comment: @Taladris that being said, of course word usage varies, pedantically, regionally, milieu. In Scotland for example foreigners would call the castle we lived in a "castle" and locals would be bemused.  Regarding the question at hand, I guess the "fair" answer to the challengers would be a castle from the setting of the game.  (Indeed, it's common for anglos in germany to call palaces "castles", which drives me nuts, as you can imagine :) )

Comment: @RobertColumbia I think Iolani Palace should be counted.  And based on how much it cost me to travel back from Aukland ~$250 US, it was pretty inexpensive.  Of course it can be very expensive to _stay_ in Hawaii, so maybe that should be an important consideration...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you live in New Zealand, then the nearest building claiming to be a "castle" is [Larnach Castle](https://www.larnachcastle.co.nz/) near Dunedin. Wikipedia describes it as a ["mock castle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larnach_Castle). It is essentially a fancy house built in the late 19th century with some features that resemble those of a traditional European castle.

If your definition of a "real castle" includes mock castles with nationally recognised gardens, then this might qualify.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of this one. If one thinks a bit more than I did before writing the question anything in New Zealand was not going to be better than "mock" simply due to shorter history. Yet, reading the Wikipedia article on mock castles, it satisfies me - that's something that people built to look and feel like a castle after historical castles stopped being built. Given that we can visit this one on a weekend, I count it as a win. I will dispense the checkmark in a few days.

Comment: Kryal Castle, in Victoria, Australia, may also qualify - but isn't as close to you as Dunedin.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mock: "adjective, 11. (...) not real". A 'mock X' is by definition not a 'real X', so I don't think this is a correct answer to the question.

Comment: @BrtH But this is true for many castles in Europe too.  For example, Balmoral Castle in the UK was only ever a large house with mock-castle add-ons, never a fortified structure; or Schloss Neuschwanstein built by Mad King Ludwig, which was the inspiration for Disney's iconic castle.  And many others such as Edinburgh Castle were originally built as defensible structures but have long since been converted/rebuilt for civilian residential use, so it's very much debatable whether they're "real".

Comment: Reminds me of [Casa Loma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_Loma) — another "mock castle" built in a British Dominion by a wealthy businessman nostalgic for Old Blighty.

Comment: While Larnach Castle looks very nice (I had to look it up since I haven't heard of it before), I'd definitely not call it a castle even by the most accommodating definition of the word.

Comment: On a similar vein, there's also Riverstone Castle down in Waitaki Bridge.  It's still a mock castle, but (in my opinion at least) looks more castle-y.

Comment: Balmoral Castle was demolished with the new house keeping the name @Graham. The current house is definitely not a castle. Castle's need walls (or cliffs) and small windows to stop enemy ordnance crushing your bed too often.

Answer (score 54):

This is going to come down to what's a "real" castle.  Wikipedia opines:

> A castle is a type of fortified structure built during the Middle Ages
> predominantly by the nobility or royalty and by military orders.
> Scholars debate the scope of the word castle, but usually consider it
> to be the private fortified residence of a lord or noble.

So it's got to be **old, fortified and a residence for nobility**, which means pretty much everything in New Zealand and Australia is right out, since they have neither medieval structures nor nobility.  Maori [pā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81) were fortified settlements not limited to nobility, so they don't quite tick the box either.

[image]

Probably the closest is thus [Japanese castles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_castle), in particular [Himeji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himeji_Castle), which looks like a castle, has an unquestionable pedigree (founded 1333, home of arguably Japan's greatest shogun Toyotomi Hideyoshi, etc) and is easily reached from Osaka.  There are many other castles in Japan, but most are concrete reconstructions of varying degrees of fidelity (Osaka Castle itself is, sadly, at the less faithful end) and further away from major airports.

Tibet and India also have various royal castles/fortresses, some [quite formidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrangarh), but these are further away from NZ.

Honorable mention goes to Indonesia, which has a series of royal palaces called *[kraton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraton_(Indonesia))*, some of which were fortified.  However, as far as I can tell all the fortified ones are in ruins now.  There are also various Dutch East Indies era fortresses in the country, but they don't really qualify as residences of the nobility.

Comment: If one looks at the etymology of "castle," one finds that it comes from s Latin word meaning "small fort," suggesting that pā should not be ruled out altogether (that is, the nobility criterion is secondary, or that the "manifestation of the power of the tribe as personified by the rangatira" [paraphrased from Wikipedia] satisfies the nobility criterion).  One can make a similar argument from the etymology of the German word _Burg._

Comment: Why should the fact that the castle is in ruins be a problem?  Many here in the UK have very little physical structure left but are still marked on maps as being a "castle".

Comment: @uɐɪ OP's game requires a "real" castle, and a pile of rocks doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: In terms of "easily reached from Osaka", of course there is also [Osaka castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osaka_Castle).

Comment: @lambshaanxy "Ruined" doesn't always mean "pile of rocks". Would this be acceptable as an example? https://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/visit/dorset/corfe-castle

Comment: @lambshaanxy What’s not real about ruins? Sure, at some point ruins become just a pile of rubble that can hardly be called a castle anymore (walking past the ruins of [Kalundborg Castle](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kalundborg_Slot_02.jpg) would probably not count as ‘visiting a castle’ to most people), but lots of castle ruins are enormous, still-standing structures. You won’t convince most who’ve visited [Chepstow Castle](https://www.visitdeanwye.co.uk/things-to-do/chepstow-castle-p1312411) that what they went to isn’t a ‘real’ castle.

Comment: Castles in Okinawa are closer to New Zealand than those in mainland Japan:
https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e7125.html I believe these would be the closest castles to New Zealand.

Comment: @spacetyper The only non-ruined castle in Okinawa is Shuri Castle at Naha, which unfortunately burned down a few years ago and won't reopen until 2026 or so.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I guess the bigger point I was getting at is I'm not sure why Osaka's castle was recommended in particular. If Okinawas' castles "don't count", then Kumamoto is still closer than Osaka...

Comment: @lambshaanxy which begs the question what's your definition of "visit". Does merely walking around the area and looking at it count? Otherwise only castles that are now museums or monuments would qualify, not any that are still used as residences or have other function (several in the Netherlands are for rent as event venues for example, otherwise closed to the public).

Comment: I've always thought it a bit weird that Japanese "castles" are, in English, often called "Japanese castles".  It's basically **insulting in both directions**. To make a rough analogy, it would be sort of like calling a magnificent Masamune samurai sword, a "Japanese sheffield steel dinner knife"!  Or perhaps calling a kimono "japanese PJs".  The construction techniques of "shiro" in Japan, are amazing, awesome, and mindboggling, but extremely different from European castellated structures (which are amazing, awesome, and mindboggling - but completely different).

Comment: Note that the shiro pictured is not .......... castellated.   Saying that it "looks like" a castle is rather like saying a car "looks like" a tank.  Or that a man's chest "looks like" a woman's chest.  :)  It's precisely and explicitly missing the salient feature.

Comment: @spacetyper the question does not mention proximity, only price.

Answer (score 14):

Wouldn't it be much easier to open the phone book, look up people named "castle" in your area and ask them whether you could visit them?

Much cheaper, much more out of the box and you surely will have some fun discussing it with your fellow players.

Comment: @Community this answer is very clear. It is suggesting that "castle" be interpreted to mean "people with the name Castle". If you disagree with this suggestion, the correct action is to downvote the answer.

Comment: ROFL! Of course, it kinda depends on the wording of the game...

Comment: On which StackExchange can I ask *“What phone book would be the least expensive to get?”*

Answer (score 10):

If you live in Auckland, there is another option in Birkdale, 47 Verbena Road

It would be interesting to know if your players would consider that visiting Himeji half a year ago beats visiting Lymington Castle a week ago...

[image: Front entrance of Lymington Castle, 47 Verbena Road, Birkdale, 2008]

Comment: Nice find, but is that open to the public?

Comment: @lambshaanxy Just buy the castle and it's open to you. It is only $3M, check here: https://homes.co.nz/address/auckland/birkdale/47-verbena-road/5jwX4

Comment: @lambshaanxy No, it's just someone's house that has very fancy brickwork on the outside. I think they do cool Halloween's there though

Answer (score 5):

I am going to disagree with lambshaanxy's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/177758/47855) that Māori [pā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81) are not castles. As quoted from Wikipedia,

> A castle is a type of fortified structure built during the Middle Ages
> predominantly by the nobility or royalty and by military orders.
> Scholars debate the scope of the word castle, but usually consider it
> to be the private fortified residence of a lord or noble.

Now, Wikipedia describes a pā as:

> In Māori culture, a great pā represented the mana (prestige or power) and strategic ability of an iwi (tribe or tribal confederacy), as personified by a rangatira (chieftain). Māori built pā in various defensible locations around the territory (rohe) of an iwi to protect fertile plantation-sites and food supplies.

A rangatira certainly appears to be a kind of noble in the sense of someone with an elevated social and political status, so one can characterize a pā as being the fortified residence of a rangatira and his subjects living under a quasi-feudal society, which sounds pretty similar to what a European castle was except that European subjects would typically have had homes and lands on the castle grounds (a "fief") rather than within the walls of the castle proper. Other Polynesian societies have similar structures of nobility.

Wikipedia mentions that a castle does not even need royalty or nobility if it is constructed by "military orders". One might make the argument that organized citizens gathering together to construct and maintain a fortification such as a pā qualifies as a militia, which is a kind of less-formal military order but an order nonetheless.

Outside of the South Pacific, the Caribbean [Castillo San Felipe del Morro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castillo_San_Felipe_del_Morro) ("Saint Phillip's Castle of the Headland") qualifies as a purely military castle. Originally built as a Spanish military base in the 1500's, it became a US Army base in 1898 and a US National Park in 1961. This would quite likely qualify as a candidate for the best castle to visit for US residents. I visited in 2012 and the structure certainly hit all of the "old medieval fortification" cultural buttons, with imposing brick and stone walls, winding spiral staircases, sentry booths, narrow gun ports high up in the structure, and turrets on the roof for the installation of massive firepower. The city of San Juan also hosts the [oldest continuously-used church building in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catedral_Metropolitana_Bas%C3%ADlica_de_San_Juan_Bautista) (itself a bona-fide medieval cathedral) in walking distance of the castle.

Comment: The main reason I have trouble aligning pā with the concept of a castle is not one of cultural use or importance, but one of building material and resulting general appearance. From a Euro-centric point of view (which in general would be shared by New Zealanders, I presume), a castle is – if not exactly by definition, then at least by very strong implication – a **stone** structure, with thick stone walls. I was not familiar with pā before reading this question, but the images Wikipedia and Google show me do not look like anything recognisably castle-like.

Comment: From purely visual clues, pā _look_ more like the type of fortified villages/towns that were not uncommon in Celtic and Germanic areas in early Europe (think Asterix’s village for an example). Those too often had a chieftain’s home at the heart and used palisades and similar fortifications to protect the land, and such chieftains were definitely equivalent to (and the forebears of) later nobility – but such villages would never be considered castles either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Most Norman castles in England built after the conquest were predominantly wood structures.  They have since been upgraded to use stone, but I don't think "stone" is necessary for a castle.

Comment: @Martin They may well have been called castles when built from wood 800+ years ago, but meanings change over time, and today, to me at least, castles are pretty much inherently built of stone. As you say, the Norman wooden ones have since been modified as stone structures. To me, that’s significant. If they hadn’t been, either we (well, I) wouldn’t think of them as ‘castles’ today, or our (my) mental image/definition of what constitutes a ‘castle’ would be different (and might well stretch to include pā).

Answer (score 0):

"Reality is that which, when you stop believing in it, doesn’t go away."

But there are also games (like Burg Appenzell), and Kryal Castle, outside of Melbourne: https://kryalcastle.com.au/

(OK, what I meant is that 'reality is a flexible concept', particularly given 'Burg Appenzell', which elevates 'game' as a valued aspect of 'reality')

Kryal Castle, which is a real place, and not hard to get to, is a 'game' too, and in-game, can be as 'real' a castle as you want it to be.
[image]

Comment: Games? (I assume that is not what you intended to write.)

Comment: @Willeke "Burg Appenzell" is a game, so I suspect that "games" _is_ what he meant to write.  I think david is suggesting that "playing a game called 'Appenzell Castle' counts as 'visiting a castle'. ".